# Cucumber doesn't allow invalid enums after update from info.cukes to io.cucumber

Tags: java, enums, cucumber

I'm migrating cucumber from old version from package `info.cukes` to latest `io.cucumber`. I noticed that old version allows invalid enum values as test arguments and returns `null` but latest version throws exception `io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments for step...`

How can I keep old behaviour in my tests after migration? Below example code to reproduce error.

```
#  feature file with test definition
Feature: Parsing enums

  Scenario: Parse enum using empty string
    Given I'm parsing enum ""
```

```java
//Step definition code
    @Given("^I'm parsing enum \"(.*?)\"$")
    public void i_m_parsing_enum(MyEnum arg1) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(arg1); // should print null but throws exception after library upgrade
    }
```

```java
//Simple enum
public enum MyEnumo {
    abc, def
}
```

Comment: Notice that, since your argument is an empty String, it cannot be instantiated to a MyEnum object. As far as I know, steps are not meant to receive null arguments. It's similar to passing the argument as a String and then invoking `MyEnum.valueOf(arg)` - you'll raise an exception. What to do with that is up to you; you may use a try-catch and handle the `IllegalArgumentException` as you prefer.

Comment: Yeah try-catch IAE is one way to do it, I wonder if there is a way to keep old behavior for transforming enums. Looks like old cucumber ignored such errors and returned null. The problem is we got already so many tests that depend on this behavior that it would require a major refactor.

Comment: You can try to use a custom parameter type, like in this example: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/ .  You'll have to change the step definition to `I'm parsing enum {myenum}` and define a `@ParameterType` method that parses the value. I've no tried myself, but it may be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @luis-iñesta comment I wrote simple try-catch using `@ParameterType` annotation:

```java
    @ParameterType("[a-z]*")
    public MyEnum myEnum(String name) {
        try {
            return MyEnum.valueOf(name);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Given("I'm parsing enum \"{myEnum}\"")
    public void i_m_parsing_enum(MyEnumo arg1) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(arg1);
    }
```

Works in this one case but I still wonder if there is some switch or parameter to keep old cucumber behaviour.